# ReactJS - Trying to access the title of an object I'm pulling from a webpage online, but getting these errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a news website with ReactJS and I'm getting three various warnings/errors when I try to run the page. I can get it to display the article link properly when I don't include the title. I still get the two first warnings in this case, but when I try to access the article's title it won't load the page at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The warnings/errors:

**Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

**Warning: Invalid value for prop `href` on  tag.**

**Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {rendered}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

LatestArticles.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Article from "./Article";

function LatestArticles() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(React.useState("waiting..."));

  function ArticleGrabber() {
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("URL")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setPosts(data);
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) =>
          console.log("Authorization failed: " + error.message)
        );
    }, []);
  }

  ArticleGrabber();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Latest Articles</h3>
      {posts.map((post, index) => (
        <ul>
          <Article key={index} post={post} />
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default LatestArticles;
```

Article.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../Article.css";

function Article(post) {
  return (
    <div className="theArticle">
      <h3>{post.post.title.rendered}</h3>
      <a href={post.post.link}>Article content</a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Article;
```

Comment: Please keep it to a single question per post. But while I'm here - the first is because you've put the `key` on the `Article` which is not the outermost element returned inside the `.map` - it needs to be on the wrapping `ul`. For the `href` one presumably `post.post.link` is something unexpected, but we don't know what that is. And for the "objects are not valid as a React child" I don't see anything in these components that can cause that error, so it's likely coming from a different component that you've not shown us.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks Robin, that fixed my first error! The others seem to be gone now too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I can see I see two Issues. 1. State inside an Inside, and the UseEffect Hook. Try this:

```
 const [waiting, setWaiting] = useState("waiting...")
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]));

    useEffect(() => {
     const articleGrabber = () => {
             fetch("URL")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setPosts(data);
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) =>
          console.log("Authorization failed: " + error.message)
        );
     }
    articleGrabber() 
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

- **when adding `keys` you need to add it to the parent element of the item (in this case the `ul` tag).**

Warning: Invalid value for prop href on tag.

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {rendered}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

**For these two errors, it might be due to how you are fetching your data, but there are a few things I would look into first:**

1. You are using react hooks within a React hook (`useState` and `React.useState`), instead make the default an empty `array`.

```html
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]));
```

2. Take your useEffect out of your function since it only runs when there are side effects… I would remove your function altogether and just stick to rendering your posts through the `useEffect` and that should work.